# Having C Program Strange Output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,b,c=10;
    a++, --b, c=50;
    printf("%d,%d,%d", a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output is `1,-1,50`? Shouldn't it be `11,9,50`?

Comment: `int a,b,c=10;` initializes only c with 10, values of a and b are undefined, in your case they appeared as 0

Comment: You can't initialize multiple variables at once (but you can do multiple *assignments* as a single statement, like `a = b = c = 10;`). And uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value (look at them as garbage). Sometimes using indeterminate values can lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Smells like homework :)

Comment: Also please don't try to do more than one thing per statement. Split up the single `a++, --b, c = 50;` statement into three statements `a++; --b; c = 50;` (on separate lines of course). That will make the code easier to read, understand, maintain and debug.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes I will use three statements to do it. @Some programmer dude

Comment: @Kamil not actually! Haha!

Comment: Did your compiler not warn you that `a` and `b` were uninitialized?  Please look into increasing the warning level, or getting a better compiler, if at all possible!  C is frustrating enough to learn as it is, but good compilers can help, if you let them.